# Java reordering and volatile issue

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I recently faced one interesting question:

For example I have class A:

```
class A {
  int a;
  int b;

  public A() {
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
  }

  public int getA() {return a;}
  public int getB() {return b;}
}
```

Class A must exist only as singleton;
So, to provide access to singleton I create class Factory:

```
class Factory {
private A a;
public A getA() {
    if (a == null) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (a == null) {
                a = new A();
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

}

As i understand, according to reordering in JVM it's possible that in case if 2 threads access Factory.getA() at the same time it's possible that one of threads will get partially constructed object and it can lead to application crash.

But in case if i make private A a; volatile can i be sure that each thread will access only completely constructed object?

So, as a conclusion, if i mark variable x as volatile, does it affect content of x.class constructor?

Answer (score 2):

> But in case if i make private A a; volatile can i be sure that each thread will access only completely constructed object?

Yes.

Consider the case where thread #1 initializes `a`.  The factory mutex ensures that only one thread at a time may create an `A`.  So we have the following sequence:

1. Thread #1 sees `a` is null
2. Thread #1 acquires the mutex.
3. Thread #1 see `a` is still null.
4. Thread #1 constructs an `A` instance, which initializes its variables.
5. Thread #1 assigns the instance reference to `a`.
6. Thread #1 releases the lock.

For a thread #2 to see `a` in the non-null state (e.g. at either the step #1 or step #3 test), that means that thread #1 must have gotten to (at least) step #5.  But that means

```
A.a = 1;                    // thread #1
```

"happens-before"

```
A.b = 2;                    // thread #1
```

"happens before"

```
write to Factory.a          // thread #1
```

"happens before"

```
read from Factory.a         // thread #2
```

"happens before"

```
access to some field of `A` // thread #2
```

Since there is a complete chain of "happens before" relations from the initialization of the fields of the new `A` in thread #1 to the field access in thread #2.  That means that thread #2 is *guaranteed* to see results of the field initialization writes ... unless there are *other* intervening writes to those fields.

Note that it is the "happens before" between the write to the volatile `a` and the subsequent read in the other thread that is the key.  If `a` is not volatile, then there isn't a complete "happens before" chain and *therefore* the execution is not "happens-before consistent"; i.e. it contains a "data race".

The terminology and reasoning that I have used / followed above comes from the Java Language Specification, [Chapter 17.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4).

Comment: This is the correct answer !.  Nice explanation Stephen

Answer (score 1):

**Volatile**

The Java volatile keyword is used to mark a Java variable as "being stored in main memory". More precisely that means, that every read of a volatile variable will be read from the computer's main memory, and not from the CPU cache, and that every write to a volatile variable will be written to main memory, and not just to the CPU cache.

Its related to memory. It wont affect constructor.

Source : Click [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html)

Comment: thanks, so could tou please advice how can i make sure that any thread will get only completely constructed object?

Comment: At least give *credit* to the [source](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html) from which you have *borrowed* this content.

Comment: @TheLostMind Ya sure . I forgot to link

Answer (score 0):

Since you want A to be a singleton my suggestion would be to make A an enum. 
Using enum :

- will solve your issue as you wont ever have a partially constructed enum
- and also using enum is the best way to implement the singleton pattern.

  ```
  enum A{
     INSTANCE(1,2);

     private int a;
     private int b;

     A(int a,int b){
         this.a=a;
         this.b=b;
      }

     public int getA(){ return a; }
     public int getB(){ return b; }
  }
  ```

Comment: i know that it's possible to do with enum, but i just interested in behaviour of "volatile"

Comment: then I would suggest you changed the question to be specific to volatile's behaviour

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things specification and implementation. If you make `a` volatile, that will solve the problem in practice, because JVM will insert a store barrier after assignment. But this will still break a specification, because `volatile` is not like `final`, it does not guarantee, that all subobjects of an object will be published. BTW, on CPUs with strong memory model a lot of bad code will work fine, but this does not mean you should write so.